# How to add image through props in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-props

I'm trying to create reusable card component and I don't know how to add the image through the props, I would appreciate your help. Now I'm using **{require("../assets/wheat.svg")}** but it doesn't work.

### CardsScreen.js

```js
import React from "react";

import styles from "../styles/card-styles/cards.css";

import Bounce from "react-reveal/Bounce";

const CardsScreen = () => {
  function Card(props) {
    return (
      <div className="card-content">
        <img className="card-image" src={props.view}></img>
        <h6 className="card-header">{props.heading}</h6>
        <p className="card-paragraph">{props.description}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="cards-container">
      <Bounce bottom>
        <Card
          view={require("../assets/wheat.svg")}
          heading="Heading"
          description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Nunc donec ullamcorper viverra lectus quis pretium volutpat eget. Aliquam ultrices tincidunt nulla commodo."
        />
      </Bounce>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardsScreen;
```

Comment: Did you double-check the path to your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are looking to add the static image, then we can import it and pass it with the view as prop.

```js
import blurImage from './images/part-blurry-image.jpg';
function Card(props) {
    return (
      <div className="card-content">
        <img className="card-image" src={props.view}></img>
        <h6 className="card-header">{props.heading}</h6>
        <p className="card-paragraph">{props.description}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
export default function CardScreen() {
  

  return (
    <div className="cards-container">
      <Card
        view={blurImage}
        heading="Heading"
        description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Nunc donec ullamcorper viverra lectus quis pretium volutpat eget. Aliquam ultrices tincidunt nulla commodo."
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should move `Card` outside of the `CardScreen` component.